# TOR Browser in a Java application: how to view the IP address of a Proxy object

Tags: ip-address, java

I'm trying to use TOR Browser in my code like this:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9150));
//add proxy to some other Java class to use
System.out.println(proxy.address()); //127.0.0.1:9150
```

It would print the locahost address instead of the IP the TOR Browser routes the traffic to. Is there a way to get the later?

Comment: Are you saying the you want the IP of the guard node?

Comment: @JSEvans I want the IP that the final site that my program connects to, sees

Comment: Did you solved your problem ?
I face the same issue : I have a Java program which connect to https website.
I want to use tor to connect https instead of my own ips.
Did you succeed to get Tor Ips ? If yes can you show me how ?
Thanks Ben

Comment: This is not a straightforward thing to do. You probably want to interact with Tor's [control protocol](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt). You should watch for stream events and identify the circuit id that belongs to your new stream. Then you can ask Tor for the circuit path and then look up the IP address belonging to the last hop in the circuit.